# Actualizar un solo dato con express.js y postgressql

Tags: nodejs, base-de-datos, postgresql, express

Cordial saludo compañer@s, vengo realizando un CRUD con express y postgres con motivos de aprendizaje, pero al momento de realizar la actualización de un solo dato, los demas elementos se colocan en null. Lo tenia en un principio con el metodo PUT, y lo he tratado de hacer con PATH, pero con ambos me arroja el mismo resultado. A continuacion dejo mi codigo.

//employee.controller.js
//Metodo donde hago el update

```
const putEmployees = async(req, res) =>{
const {id} = req.params;
const {name, salary} = req.body;
const response = await pool.query(`UPDATE employee SET name = $1, salary = $2 WHERE id = $3`,[name, salary, id]);
try {
    if(response.rowCount>0){
        return res.status(200).send({
            id,
            message:'Actualizado'
        })
    }
    res.status(404).send({message:`No hay elemento con el id:${id}`}); 
} catch (error) {
    res.status(404).send(error)
}
```

}

//employee.routes.js

```
router.patch('/employees/:id', putEmployees )
```

Comment: que datos contienen: name, salary, id

Comment: el id se  lo envio por params, localhost:3000/employee/1, mientras que name y salary lo envio por body, pero quiero actualizar uno solo, sea name o slaary y que se conserve el valor que ya tenia, y no lo remplace por null

Comment: yo no he preguntando de donde vienen los datos... pregunte que contienen los datos en el momento que lo ejecutas ... ***que datos contienen: name, salary, id***

Comment: un string y un int respectivamente

Comment: yo no he preguntando que tipo de datos tare... pregunte que contienen los datos en el momento que lo ejecutas ... ***que datos contienen: name, salary, id***